# Equivalent axioms for a group

Tags: group-theory

**Claim:** Assume $(G,\times)$ is a set with an associative binary operation such that $\forall a,b\in G$ the equations $ax=b$ and $ya=b$ have a unique solution in $G$. Then $G$ is a group.

**Thought:** Let $a\in G$. An identity must be the unique solution $e$ to $ax=a$. Then an inverse of $a$ is the unique solition to $ax=e$. Hence $G$ is a group.

**Question:** How can we see that the above $e$ is indeed an identity?

Comment: Why would *anyone* downvote a question as the above one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right so, assume the given properties. I'm not going to reference each step of associativity.

$a\in G$, $\exists \;e_{ra},e_{\small la} \in G $ such that:

$ae_{ra}=a$ and $e_{\small la}a=a$

Also there exists $x,y \in G$ such that,

$ax=e_{ra}$ and $ya=e_{la}$

So

$e_{ra}=ax=e_{la}ax=e_{la}e_{ra}=yae_{ra}=ya=e_{la}$.

We can drop the l and r and say $e_a$

Finally $\exists \; x',y' \in G$ such that

$ax'=e_b$ and $y'b=e_a$

So

$e_b=ax'=e_aax'=e_ae_b=y'be_b=y'b=e_a$

Also you can see that from before with

$ax=e_{a}$ and $ya=e_{a}$

that

$e_a=ax=e_aax=e_ae_a$.

Now $e_a e_a=axya=e_a$. Envoking uniqueness,

$axy=y \implies e_ay=y$ and

$xya=x \implies xe_a=x$

and $x=xe_a=yax=ye_a=y$.

So we can talk uniquely about $a^{-1}$.

Comment: You are missing something. One needs to consider for $a\in G$ the elements $e_{al}$ and also prove that $\forall a,b\in G (e_{al}=e_{bl})$. That is, given a solution $e$ to $ax=a$, one need to show that $\forall b\in G(be=b)$.

Comment: sure I'll add that now. Combined with the existence of an inverse

Comment: there might be a shorter way, and it seems according to the book by Gertrude Ehrlich "Fundamental Concepts of Abstract Algebra" that you don't need uniqueness. But that might make it longer again

Comment: @Student Hopefully that's better

Comment: Yes, thank you. Now $G$ is a group, thus uniqueness of the identity and the inverses follows from their existence.